# Angular custom directive to format text input to number

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am trying to create a custom directive that formats a text input to a desired number format. The directive below currently works on blur and focus, however does not format the text string on page load. I have also tried AfterViewInit with no luck. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can also cause the input to be formatted on load?

```
 import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({ 
    selector: '[myCurrencyFormatter]', 
    // providers: [NgModel] 
})
export class CustomCurrencyDirective implements OnInit {
    private el: HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
  ) {
    this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.el.value =  this.el.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }

  @HostListener("focus", ["$event.target.value"])
  onFocus(value) {
    this.el.value = value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }

  @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])
  onBlur(value) {
    this.el.value = value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }
}
```

here is the html input code:

```
        <div *ngFor="let dateCell of revenueFormService.datesAssoc" [ngStyle]="{width: columnWidth + 'px'}" class="cell" data-index="dateCell.key" data-date="dateCell.date">
            <input 
                [(ngModel)]="modelValues[dateCell.key]" 
                type="text" 
                class="cell-input" 
                placeholder="0" 
                alignText="right" 
                (change)="onCellChange(dateCell, $event)"
                [disabled]="cellIsEditable(dateCell)"
                [class.active]="cellIsEditable(dateCell)"
                myCurrencyFormatter
            >
        </div>
```

Comment: Please post complete code for HTML and the related component.

Answer (score 0):

It already does so with:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.el.value =  this.el.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }
```

But I guess the problem could be more related to timing. By the time data is assigned to input's `value`, `ngOngInit()` on the directive has already run. And afterwards, you don't detect changes on the input's `value`. It's just a guess, but I would listen to changes on the input value, and reformat it on changes.

The problem now become detecting a change in input value. DOM events' like `change` etc won't work. I can only come up with `@Input` binding the directive to get the change, and then `ngOnChanges` run the format again but that doesn't seem right...

But why you do this? `[(ngModel)]="modelValues[dateCell.key]"` you pass in a completely regular number `123456789` which is then formated to `123,456,789` and then save that as the obj's value (ngModel is two way bined)? Won't that screw things up?

If I was you I would create a simple pipe to do this. Keep the actual value unchanged, but format it for the user.

```html
<input myCurrencyFormatter value="{{ modelValues | myCurrentyFormat}}"/>
```

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'myCurrentyFormat' })
export class MyCurrentyFormat implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number): string {
    return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
  }
}
```

Examples: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-directive-7bsybc?file=app%2Fapp.component.html